# Leader Election over SQS/SNS?

Tags: distributed-computing, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm using [the bully algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bully_algorithm) to perform leader election among a cluster of machines. I plan to use a topic as the communication medium. Has anyone tried using [SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sqs/)/[SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sns/) for something like the bully algorithm before? What problems did you experience? What problems should I expect to hit?

Comment: Depending on your exact use-case, you may be able to eliminate the need for a leader altogether by using Amazon SWF to co-ordinate the work: http://aws.amazon.com/swf/

Answer (score 3):

Well, you should be aware that SNS does not have published SLAs on message end-to-end times.  Personally if I was looking to implement something like that I would use DynamoDB and have each machine create an item in a table and then update it's item with a new timestamp every couple seconds.  Then each machine queries that table and if a machine hasn't updated in some amount of time then it is considered dead.

I'm not sure exactly what your plan was for using SNS to do this, but if you want to provide more details on your design I might be able to comment.